# My Joomla Administrator password changed

Tags: joomla

Someone changed my Joomla Administrator password. How is that possible because only I have all cpanel details. But I found several unwanted entries in my data base table. Is it hacking or something, please guide me.

Comment: Just because **you** have all admin login details, doesn't mean people can't perform SQL injections. My guess is that you're using a vulnerable extension or an older version of Joomla that can be exploited.

Comment: Yes I am using modules/plugins from third parties. But now what to do and how to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your website has been hacked.

Do you have any components/modules/plugins from third parties? They can have some vulnerabilities that had been exploited by someone (already happened to me).

Comment: Yes I am using modules/plugins from third parties. But now what to do and how to find a solution for this?